# OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor analog for CLI application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is there any analog of [`OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html) for CLI application?

I am trying to use Spring's `CrudRepository` with JPA data source backed by Hibernate 4 in CLI application.

My `main` method creates an instance of the class containing this method and injects services using `context.getBeanFactory().autowireBean(object);`.

Services for data fetching have methods annotated with `@Transactional`. These methods invoke `CrudRepository`'s methods.

But I receive `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` when I try to manage related entities in the CLI application.

Is there any workaround to have lazy loading working in the CLI application outside the `@Transactional` methods like [`OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html) for web applications?

Look at the following snippet:

```
public class test {

    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test test = new test();
        //injecting dependencies into test
        test.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        User user = userService.findById(42);
        System.out.println(user.getLogin()); //User was fetched successfully
        Address address = new Address("London");
        user.addAddress(address);//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say there isn't one for CLI because there's no notion of View as in MVC pattern. However I suspect your problem is due to ineffective declarative transaction management.

For a CLI application, ensure you have properly setup datasource, EntityManagerFactory and [declarative transaction managemeent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative).

A good practice is to enclose your business / DAO code in service / repository classes annotated with `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component` or other appropriate spring annotation, create your own ApplicationContext and obtain reference to your services:

```
// UserDAO.java ----------------------------------------
@Repository
public class UserDAO {
  @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

  @Transactional
  public User findById(long id) {
    // ...
  }
}

// UserService.java ----------------------------------------
@Service
public class UserService {
  @Autowired private UserDAO userDAO;
  // ...
}

// MainClass.java ----------------------------------------
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/root-context.xml");
    UserService userService = context.getBean(UserService.class);

    // more code here..

    context.close();
  }
}
```

Autowiring and declarative transaction will still work as per normal as long as the bean is created by Spring container.